# How to build imapsync for windows?

Tags: windows, github, build, imapsync

I need to migrate a lot of IMAP accounts to a new server and `imapsync` seems like a good tool to do it. They have a [github repo](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync) but there are no instructions on how to build it for Windows (although their documentation states that it works on windows). Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### There are no instructions on how to build it for Windows

Yes there are, but it is easier just to install the windows binary.

> # $Id: README_Windows.txt,v 1.11 2018/05/05 22:46:01 gilles Exp gilles $
>
> #
>
> # This is the README_Windows.txt file for imapsync
>
> # imapsync : IMAP sync and migrate tool.
>
> WINDOWS
>
> =======
>
> There is two ways to install and use imapsync on Windows systems: A)
>   or B).
>
> Standard users should take the A) way, the simplest way.
>
> Developers, or powerful users that want to build their own
>   imapsync.exe or modify it, have to consider the B) way, the complex
>   but powerful way.
>
> A) Simplest way
>
> A.1) Get imapsync.
>
> Get imapsync at https://imapsync.lamiral.info/ You'll then have access
>   to a zip archive file named imapsync_1.xxx.zip where 1.xxx is the
>   imapsync release number.
>
> A.2) Extract the zip file in a folder where you will work with
>   imapsync.
>
> You can work on the Desktop since the zip file extraction creates a
>   unique folder named imapsync_1.xxx (where 1.xxx is the imapsync 
>   release number).
>
> A.3) Check the folder
>
> In the folder extracted imapsync_1.xxx you see 6 files and 2
>   directories:
>
> - README_Windows.txt     is the current file you are reading.
> - README.txt             is the imapsync general document.
> - FAQ.d/*                FAQs are a good read when something goes wrong.
> - imapsync_example.bat   is a simple batch file example you will copy and edit.
> - sync_loop_windows.bat  is a batch file example for syncing many accounts.
> - file.txt               is an input file example for syncing many accounts.
> - imapsync.exe           is the imapsync binary. You don't have to run it directly.
> - Cook/                  is the directory to build imapsync.exe from its source, 
>                          for the B) way and expert users.
>
> You can copy or rename imapsync_example.bat as you wish as long as 
>   its extension remains ".bat". On Windows systems .bat extension  means
>   "I'm a batch script". Same thing for sync_loop_windows.bat. The batch
>   scripts have to stay in the same directory than  imapsync.exe because
>   of the way they call imapsync.exe,  they use ".\imapsync.exe", so let
>   them be in the same directory. Or change the path .\ to whatever you
>   want if you understand what  you're doing.
>
> For the rest of this documentation I assume you copied
>   imapsync_example.bat to a file named imapsync_stuff.bat
>
> A.4) Edit the batch file
>
> Edit imapsync_stuff.bat and change the values with yours. In order to
>   edit it you have do a right click on it and select "modify" in the
>   list presented in the small window menu. Notepad or Notepadd++ are
>   very good editors to modify it. Office Word or any powerful text
>   processor are not good for that job,  don't use them!
>
> Files FAQ.txt and FAQ.d/* contain many tips and special options
>   sometimes needed by specific imap server softwares like Exchange or
>   Gmail.
>
> A.5) Run the batch file
>
> To run imapsync with your values just double-click on  the batch file
>   imapsync_stuff.bat
>
> You do not need to have administrator privileges to run imapsync.
>
> A.6) Loop on A.5) A.6) edit, run, edit, run etc.
>
> Loop the process of editing and running imapsync until you solve all
>   issues and all values suit your needs.
>
> A.7) Look the sync running. You can abort it at any time with a 
>        quick double ctrl-c, hit ctrl-c twice within one second.
>        (a single ctrl-c will reconnect to both imap servers)
>
> A.8) When the sync is finished you can find the whole log of the
>   output  in the folder named "LOG_imapsync", the logfile name is based
>   on the launching date, hour, minute, second, miliseconds and the 
>   user2 parameter. There is one logfile per run. The logfile name is
>   printed at the end of the imapsync run. If you do not want logging to
>   a file then use option --nolog
>
> B) Hard way.
>
> It is the hard way because it installs all software
>   dependencies. This is the way for modifying imapsync.exe if needed.
>
> B.1) Install Perl if it isn't already installed.   Strawberry Perl is
>   a very good candidate   http://strawberryperl.com/   I use 5.26.0.1
>   (31 may 2017) but previous and later releases    should work (5.18 and
>   5.20 do) as well.
>
> B.2) Go into the Cook/ directory B.3) Double-clic build_exe.bat
>
> It should create a binary imapsync.exe in the current Cook/ directory.
>
> B.4) Move imapsync.exe in the upper directory and follow instructions
>   from A.3) to A.8)

Source [imapsync/README_Windows.txt at master · imapsync/imapsync](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync/blob/master/README_Windows.txt)

Comment: it's not free, is it? the website is hecking confusing